# SAGA functions not writing output raster using QGIS 3?

Tags: qgis, raster, saga, hydrology

I'm using QGIS 3.0, using a SRTM 1 Arc Second to perform hydrological analysis using some of SAGA functions (such as Fill Sinks), if I choose temporary output, it works fine; if I choose to save to file, it comes out with an error.

The same process works fine on QGIS 2.18, and I did try two different machines and the same problem occured.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It works for me. I use QGIS 3 in GNU/Linux Debian 64 bits.

Comment: After the temporary output is created, can you save it by the right click, save as...  method?

Comment: Yes, I can use the save as - and sorry, I didn't mention that I'm working mostly with Windows 10 workstations